# Updated texlive and now TexShop doesn't work

Tags: mac, texlive-2019

---

**Update:** This problem seems to have magically resolved itself after a quick "trash aux files". I guess it was not a problem with the TexLive installation, but just the usual kind of random problem that's fixed by removing the aux files. I'm not sure whether to delete the question or leave it here in case this note helps someone.

---

After years of putting it off because I was afraid something bad would happen, I just updated TexLive on my Mac. I did so by following the not very straightforward instructions [here](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-unix-download.html) to install a new version.

However, now when I try to compile a LaTeX document in TexShop, it pops up the latex console, but no text appears in it, and no compilation takes place.

I suppose that TexShop is not finding the new TexLive installation for some reason, but how can I diagnose and fix the problem?

One thing I noticed: when I was installing TexLive, I noticed that the installer seemed to call it TexLive 2020 rather than 2019, but during the last step, I had to run an installer called "TexDist-2019.pkg". Could the reason be to do with that?

If I run `latex -v` at the terminal the first line of output is

> pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/MacPorts 2019.50896_0)

So I guess it is installed, the problem is just with applications being able to find it.

I should note also that I'm on OS X 10.11 El Capitan and have no intention of upgrading until my current machine departs this mortal coil.

Comment: @Mico I guess you mean the terminal-based route (I don't think it uses macports, though I could be wrong). The reason is that I'm on OS X 10.11 and don't intend to upgrade - the direct download only supports 10.12 and above.

Comment: @Mico no, because I followed the prominent link on the MacTex home page that says "You can also install TeX Live 2019 using the TeX Live Unix Install Script. This method supports MacOS 10.6, Snow Leopard, and higher and runs on Intel processors." I figured that if I can install TexLive 2019 on my 10.11 Intel machine, that would make more sense than trying to get an older TeXLive to work?

Comment: @Mico no aggravation experienced! Sorry if my wording gave that impression!

Comment: (unfortunate wording edited - I really didn't meant to imply I was irritated by the comment)